# how to change property name by argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have some function:

```
function funcName(first_data, SECOND_DATA) {
    // ...some code here...
    data: {dontMatterProp: dontMatterVal, SECOND_DATA: SECOND_DATA},
    // ...some code.....
}
```

I need that my property ***name*** 'SECOND_DATA' changes too!
for example in php a could do something like {SECOND_DATA}...

Comment: Try `data[SECOND_DATA] = SECOND_DATA;`

Comment: data[0] = SECOND_DATA works ok. But data[SECOND_DATA] = SECOND_DATA don't work

Comment: give me plase an example of SECOND_DATA value !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
function funcName(first_data, SECOND_DATA_KEY, SECOND_DATA_VALUE) {
  // ...some code here...
  x = {}
  x.data = {dontMatterProp: dontMatterVal}
  x.data[SECOND_DATA_KEY] = SECOND_DATA_VALUE
  // ...some code.....
}
```

If you just want the key to be equal to the value, you could just do

`x.data[SECOND_DATA] = SECOND_DATA`

But that's a little odd. Why map something to itself? No value necessary, you can just verify that the key exists if that's the case...

You can use brackets for dynamic keys in javascript. So,

```
var x = {}
x['something'] = 'test'
// x === { 'something': 'test' }

x[something] = 'test2'
// error: something is undefined

var something = 'hello'
x[something] = 'test3'
// x === { 'something': 'test', 'hello': 'test3' }
```

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
data[SECOND_DATA] = SECOND_DATA; // assign the value
```

If you just use:

```
var data = { SECOND_DATA: SECOND_DATA };
```

using object notation - the property name will ALWAYS be `SECOND_DATA`

Comment: He claimed that SECOND_DATA would be a string in the comments to his question.

Comment: Missed that... so yeah he wants to avoid object notation, and use data[ ... ] instead. (Not using { ... } )